# Maximal speed of animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

The task is to change black square to white square on the screen very quickly. The maximal frequency that I could achieve is 60Hz. But, according to the properties of AMOLED displays, they can change pixel color during 1 ms or less, so the maximal frequency should be, theoretically, more than 1000 Hz. What is the limit of such frequency? What is the variance of this limit among different devices? And how to achieve maximal frequencies of such simple "blinking" animation?

Comment: try SurfaceView to make it faster

Comment: I've tried exactly SurfaceView with AnimationDrawable and simple background switching. Result is the same, but using AnimationDrawable resulted in more "smooth" blinking (I've checked it using light detector). The maximal frequency was the same for both cases.

Comment: no no no, dont use AnimationDrawable, draw everything using a Canvas methods

Comment: Canvas methods are slower and give less smooth blinking. I need blinks with precise duration

Comment: so sychronize the blinks with time